# MySql - select record if available otherwise select next or previous priority record

Tags: mysql, case

I have this table structure

Exercises
`ExercisesId   |  Name | PriorityWoman | PriorityMan | RefEquipment  |  MuscleBits`

From where I am selecting priority wise Exercises . I have 1 to 9 priority levels.

Now, I am seleting data from table for certain priority level, What I want to do is suppose if 6 Priority not available then I want to select next lowest(i.e priority 7/8/9) priority Exercises in the table OR previous Higest(i.e priority 5/4/3/2/1) Exercises if next is not available...

Here what I have done so far

```
SELECT Exercises.*,
       GymToEquipment.RefEquipment
FROM Exercises,
     GymToEquipment
WHERE GymToEquipment.RefGym = '29'
  AND GymToEquipment.RefEquipment = Exercises.RefEquipment
  AND (CASE
           WHEN Exercises.MuscleBits IN('Back hand',
                                        'Front hand',
                                        'Shoulders',
                                        'Back') THEN Exercises.PriorityWoman IN (1)
           WHEN Exercises.MuscleBits IN('Stomach') THEN Exercises.PriorityWoman IN (3)
           WHEN Exercises.MuscleBits IN('Chest') THEN Exercises.PriorityWoman IN (2)
           ELSE Exercises.PriorityWoman IN (7)
       END)
```

**Sample Data**

> CREATE TABLE exercises( ExerciseId int(11) NOT NULL, Name varchar(255)
>   COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, PriorityMan int(11) NOT NULL,
>   PriorityWoman int(11) NOT NULL, Image text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT
>   NULL, RefEquipment int(11) DEFAULT NULL, MuscleBits text COLLATE
>   utf8_unicode_ci );
>
> INSERT INTO
>
> exercises(ExerciseId,Name,PriorityMan,PriorityWoman,Image,RefEquipment,MuscleBits)
>   VALUES
>   (2,'e1',1,3,'localhost/gyms/images/1525077944_5ae6d7b85dab8.png',4,'Legs'),
>   (3,'e2',2,6,'localhost/gyms/images/1525079863_5ae6df371e6b7.png',5,'Legs'),
>   (4,'e3',3,7,'localhost/gyms/images/1525079494_5ae6ddc68da4d.png',6,'Legs'),(
>   5,'e4',2,6,'localhost/gyms/images/1525079530_5ae6ddea877cf.png',4,'Legs'),
>   (6,'e5',3,7,'localhost/gyms/images/1525079559_5ae6de078149e.png',4,'Legs'),
>   (7,'e6',6,8,'localhost/gyms/images/1525079627_5ae6de4b5cb8b.png',9,'Legs'),
>   (8,'e7',7,1,'localhost/gyms/images/1525079672_5ae6de7894667.png',10,'Legs'),
>   (9,'e8',8,2,'localhost/gyms/images/1525079702_5ae6de96126bf.png',11,'Legs'),
>   (10,'e9',9,4,'localhost/gyms/images/1525079750_5ae6dec61ea58.png',12,'Legs'),
>   (11,'e10',10,5,'localhost/gyms/images/1525079779_5ae6dee33bda9.png',12,'Legs'),
>   (13,'e11',1,1,'localhost/gyms/images/1525081036_5ae6e3cc869df.png',14,'Back'),
>   (14,'e12',2,2,'localhost/gyms/images/1525081270_5ae6e4b6bd066.png',31,'Back'),
>   (15,'e13',3,3,'localhost/gyms/images/1525081310_5ae6e4dea9479.png',16,'Back'),
>   (16,'e14',4,4,'localhost/gyms/images/1525081375_5ae6e51f06e44.png',17,'Back'),
>   (17,'e15',5,5,'localhost/gyms/images/1525081416_5ae6e548dca82.png',14,'Back'),
>   (18,'e16',6,6,'localhost/gyms/images/1525081466_5ae6e57a839b7.png',14,'Back'),
>   (19,'e17',7,7,'localhost/gyms/images/1525081507_5ae6e5a3c4861.png',14,'Back'),
>   (20,'e19',8,8,'localhost/gyms/images/1525081532_5ae6e5bc8c703.png',14,'Back'),
>   (21,'e20',9,9,'localhost/gyms/images/1525081577_5ae6e5e9c7730.png',44,'Back'),
>   (22,'e21',10,10,'localhost/gyms/images/1525081618_5ae6e6125b122.png',44,'Back'),
>   (23,'e22',1,1,'localhost/gyms/images/1525081756_5ae6e69ce77cd.png',24,'Chest'),
>   (24,'e23',2,2,'localhost/gyms/images/1525081789_5ae6e6bd3d1fe.png',25,'Chest'),
>   (25,'e24',3,3,'localhost/gyms/images/1525081813_5ae6e6d55e80c.png',25,'Chest'),
>   (26,'e25',4,4,'localhost/gyms/images/1525081854_5ae6e6fe10c7d.png',27,'Chest'),
>   (27,'26',5,5,'localhost/gyms/images/1525081905_5ae6e73158153.png',28,'Chest'),
>   (28,'27',6,6,'localhost/gyms/images/1525081927_5ae6e74752a0e.png',28,'Chest'),
>   (29,'28',1,2,'localhost/gyms/images/1525082103_5ae6e7f774930.png',30,'Shoulders'),
>   (30,'29',2,1,'localhost/gyms/images/1525082069_5ae6e7d5382c6.png',31,'Shoulders'),
>   (31,'30',3,3,'localhost/gyms/images/1525082168_5ae6e838e7091.png',32,'Shoulders'),
>   (32,'31',4,4,'localhost/gyms/images/1525082215_5ae6e867a7600.png',32,'Shoulders'),
>   (33,'32',5,5,'localhost/gyms/images/1525082289_5ae6e8b16dc8c.png',34,'Shoulders'),
>   (34,'33',1,1,'localhost/gyms/images/1525082321_5ae6e8d17cc8e.png',35,'Stomach'),
>   (35,'34',2,2,'localhost/gyms/images/1525082347_5ae6e8ebc1f03.png',36,'Stomach'),
>   (36,'35',3,3,'localhost/gyms/images/1525082367_5ae6e8ff6adb4.png',36,'Stomach'),
>   (37,'36',1,1,'localhost/gyms/images/1525082436_5ae6e94408290.png',40,'Front
>   hand'),
>   (38,'37',2,2,'localhost/gyms/images/1525082460_5ae6e95c6d067.png',38,'Front
>   hand'),
>   (39,'38',3,3,'localhost/gyms/images/1525082483_5ae6e9733a0b5.png',40,'Front
>   hand'),
>   (40,'39',1,3,'localhost/gyms/images/1525082533_5ae6e9a5a2b42.png',41,'Back
>   hand'),
>   (41,'40',2,1,'localhost/gyms/images/1525082574_5ae6e9cea82f3.png',42,'Back
>   hand');

**Edit**

There are 6 different muscle_bits Legs,Chest,... etc. I am selecting one group with priority `3` suppose `(Legs, Chest)` if priority 3 is not available in `Legs` muscle bit only then select another exercise only for `Legs` Muscle bit

**Expected Output** (I ll format data later I just need to pull exercises from table)

{"Days":[{"DayNumber":0,"TimePeriod":0,"Muscles":[{"MuscleId":"Legs","Excercises":[{"Excerciseid":"6","Deviceid":"4","ExcerciseSet":[{"Setnumber":1,"Repetitions":30,"Weight":56.55,"Interval":40},{"Setnumber":2,"Repetitions":30,"Weight":56.55,"Interval":40}]}]},{"MuscleId":"Back","Excercises":[{"Excerciseid":"15","Deviceid":"16","ExcerciseSet":[{"Setnumber":1,"Repetitions":30,"Weight":60.9,"Interval":40},{"Setnumber":2,"Repetitions":30,"Weight":60.9,"Interval":40}]}]},{"MuscleId":"Chest","Excercises":[{"Excerciseid":"25","Deviceid":"25","ExcerciseSet":[{"Setnumber":1,"Repetitions":30,"Weight":60.9,"Interval":40},{"Setnumber":2,"Repetitions":30,"Weight":60.9,"Interval":40}]}]},{"MuscleId":"Shoulders","Excercises":[{"Excerciseid":"31","Deviceid":"32","ExcerciseSet":[{"Setnumber":1,"Repetitions":30,"Weight":45.24,"Interval":40},{"Setnumber":2,"Repetitions":30,"Weight":45.24,"Interval":40}]}]},{"MuscleId":"Stomach","Excercises":[{"Excerciseid":"36","Deviceid":"36","ExcerciseSet":[{"Setnumber":1,"Repetitions":30,"Weight":52.2,"Interval":40},{"Setnumber":2,"Repetitions":30,"Weight":52.2,"Interval":40}]}]},{"MuscleId":"Front hand","Excercises":[{"Excerciseid":"39","Deviceid":"40","ExcerciseSet":[{"Setnumber":1,"Repetitions":30,"Weight":43.935,"Interval":40},{"Setnumber":2,"Repetitions":30,"Weight":43.935,"Interval":40}]}]}]}]}

Comment: Sample data would be helpful.

Comment: sample data updated

Comment: **_@parish_**: update is not readable. you better add records. not mysql dump

Comment: I have added json Copy paste to  view it at http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: Is your data stored as json? if not then edit your question by copying from http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcf32a

Comment: I am not clear what you are asking for. Your data has many exercise groups (legs,stomach,chest etc) are you saying that if 6 is not available in each of these groups then get the next priority for that group. Expected output , as text , based on your sample data added to the question would help.

Comment: @Data is not stored in json it is in table format. I have edit the question please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear to me how your data hangs together since you haven't included any for GymToEquipment. You may be able to do something using union (which will find value if exists, next highest and next lowest priority for each musclebit) with limit to get appropriate values for example

```
SET @LEGS = 3;SET @BACK = 7;

SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT 'LEG' AS EXCERCISE, S.* FROM
(
SELECT EXERCISEID,PRIORITYWOMAN FROM EXERCISES WHERE PRIORITYWOMAN = @LEGS AND MUSCLEBITS = 'LEGS' 
UNION 
SELECT EXERCISEID,PRIORITYWOMAN FROM EXERCISES 
    WHERE PRIORITYWOMAN  = (SELECT MIN(E1.PRIORITYWOMAN) FROM EXERCISES E1 WHERE E1.PRIORITYWOMAN > @LEGS AND MUSCLEBITS = 'LEGS' 
    LIMIT 1) 
UNION
SELECT EXERCISEID,PRIORITYWOMAN FROM EXERCISES 
 WHERE PRIORITYWOMAN  = (SELECT MAX(E1.PRIORITYWOMAN) FROM EXERCISES E1 WHERE E1.PRIORITYWOMAN < @LEGS AND MUSCLEBITS = 'LEGS' 
    ORDER BY PRIORITYWOMAN DESC LIMIT 1) 
UNION  
SELECT 9999,999 FROM DUAL
) S
LIMIT 1
) A
UNION
(SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT 'BACK' AS EXERCISE, S.* FROM
(
SELECT EXERCISEID,PRIORITYWOMAN FROM EXERCISES WHERE PRIORITYWOMAN = @BACK AND MUSCLEBITS = 'BACK' 
UNION 
SELECT EXERCISEID,PRIORITYWOMAN FROM EXERCISES 
    WHERE PRIORITYWOMAN  = (SELECT MIN(E1.PRIORITYWOMAN) FROM EXERCISES E1 WHERE E1.PRIORITYWOMAN > @BACK AND MUSCLEBITS = 'BACK' 
    LIMIT 1) 
UNION
SELECT EXERCISEID,PRIORITYWOMAN FROM EXERCISES 
 WHERE PRIORITYWOMAN  = (SELECT MAX(E1.PRIORITYWOMAN) FROM EXERCISES E1 WHERE E1.PRIORITYWOMAN < @BACK AND MUSCLEBITS = 'BACK' 
    ORDER BY PRIORITYWOMAN DESC LIMIT 1) 
UNION  
SELECT 9999,999 FROM DUAL
) S
LIMIT 1
) B
)
```

Result

```
+-----------+------------+---------------+
| EXCERCISE | EXERCISEID | PRIORITYWOMAN |
+-----------+------------+---------------+
| LEG       |          2 |             3 |
| BACK      |         19 |             7 |
+-----------+------------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

And Yes I know it's horrible.